# Setting a cookie in a different path, relative to the user's current URL path

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in a users session, relative to a path different than where the user currently is. (That is, the path I want the cookie to be relative to is "/", where the user is currently in in "/_CGI". I'm trying the following, but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(setMobileBrowsingCookie());

    function setMobileBrowsingCookie()
    {
        document.cookie = "WF_BROWSING_MODE=MOBILE; path=/";
    }
</script>
```

From my Chrome developer console, I can see the cookie being set when I remove the optional `path=/` arg, but if I remove it, the cookie will be set relative to the CGI handle `/_CGI`. Is the `path` arg not being used correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the cookie expiration as well.

```
document.cookie = 'WF_BROWSING_MODE=MOBILE; expires=Fri, 30 Aug 2012 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

Comment: Got it, I'll try this now. What if I'm not interested in the expiration of the cookie? Is it possible to ignore this optional arg and only pass in the `path` arg?

Comment: I would always specify the date such that the cookie knows when it is to expire. Different browsers may behave differently without a expires value being explicitly defined (with most just expiring to end of session I believe).

Comment: Sorry Mike, I didn't mean to mark the question as resolved. The cookie doesn't seem to work when I add the `path=/` arg to the cookie declaration. Right now, I'm calling it like this: `document.cookie = 'WF_BROWSING_MODE=MOBILE; expires=' + cookie_date + '; path=/';`  and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sal So what was did you do to finally make it work (so I can update my answer if needed)?

Comment: Well, I'm actually trying to override an existing cookie. For some reason, browsers don't want to override the existing cookies, so when I passed the `path=/` arg, it would ignore it. When I didn't pass the `path` arg, it would set the path relative to the user's current state. You're answer made me realize this, so I'll just ask another question about properly overriding an existing cookie. Thanks!